# why line number in .debug_line shows 0?

Tags: clang, toolchain, dwarf, addr2line

Why I'm seeing so many 0 Line number addresses in recently file compiled by clang?

like the result from llvm-dwarfdump below:

```
Address            Line   Column File   ISA Discriminator Flags
------------------ ------ ------ ------ --- ------------- -------------
0x0000000000000000    287      0      4   0             0  is_stmt
0x0000000000000030    287      0      4   0             0  is_stmt prologue_end
**0x0000000000000034      0      0      4   0             0**
0x0000000000000038    293      2      4   0             0  is_stmt
**0x0000000000000060      0      2      4   0             0**
0x0000000000000064    300      6      4   0             0  is_stmt
0x000000000000006c    295     38      4   0             0  is_stmt
0x0000000000000070    297     14      4   0             0  is_stmt
0x0000000000000074    300      6      4   0             0  is_stmt
0x0000000000000078    300      6      4   0             0
0x000000000000007c      0      6      4   0             0
0x0000000000000080    301      3      4   0             0  is_stmt
0x0000000000000088      0      0      4   0             0
0x000000000000008c    301      3      4   0             0
0x0000000000000090    306     26      4   0             0  is_stmt
0x00000000000000a0    306     40      4   0             0
0x00000000000000a8    270     11      4   0             0  is_stmt
0x00000000000000ac    273     15      4   0             0  is_stmt
0x00000000000000b0    271     32      4   0             0  is_stmt
0x00000000000000b4    273     43      4   0             0  is_stmt
```

what compiler flag is causing it?

Comment: What version of Clang are you using?

Comment: clang in Android 12